# Setting button background programmatically removes it from screen

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying to change background color of a button programmatically but when i change its color button disappears from screen.

Here is button in layout

```
<Button                
  android:id="@+id/ibtn_EA_ColorPick_new"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
  android:background="@drawable/clr_btn"
  />
```

and here is how i am changing its background

```
btn_ColorPick.setBackgroundColor(btn_ColorPick.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.BlackColor));
```

I have also tried

```
btn_ColorPick.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BlackColor));
```

but same result

Comment: Have you tried removing `android:background="@drawable/clr_btn"` from `xml` and instead add a `bacgroundColor="@android:colors/red"` and then try if same behaviour

Comment: is your activity background and button color same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ImageButton -

```
    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/ibtn_EA_ColorPick_new"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:src="@drawable/clr_btn"
      android:background="@drawable/red_color"
         />

btn_ColorPick.setBackgroundColor(->ur color <-);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
btn_ColorPick.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //import of android.graphics.Color
```

Another method is this:

```
bt_exButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFBBAA00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY); //import od import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
```

Maybe you try to change the color to the same as the background of the activity is and it disappears, because it is the same color...